# How to compare to MySQL tables and display the differences?

Tags: php, mysql

We get a daily feed which is used to populate a MySQL database. I would like to compare the new feed to the previous one to see what has changed, added or even deleted. I'm working in MySQL and PHP. How can this best be accomplished in MySQL? I'm thinking it should take the previous feed which is a MySQL table and compare it to the new feed which is also stored as a MySQL table. But how do I do this so it retrieves those rows which are not found in the new MySQL table? Thanks!

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you want to compare in the tables? strings, paragraphs or multiple paragraphs etc. Do you have any key to distinguish between the feeds?

Comment: Are you modifying the the mirror on your site? If not, you could use [`rsync`](http://www.oreillynet.com/linux/cmd/cmd.csp?path=r/rsync) to merge the underlying table files. I swear I've also seen someone do a `grep` compare of two files to find the lines that differ. If it's not a very big dataset, you could just drop the old and import the new database as well.

Comment: @PCoder I want to compare the tables that have fields such as customer_record_number,address1,address2,city,state,zip,phone,email. The customer_record_number would be the key.

Comment: @Jared Farrish The dataset comes as a JSON file format which gets parsed and stored in the MySQL table. The purpose of the comparison is to identify those rows which have been changed by the new feed to create a report to alert staff of the changes. The staff then does a number of different functions base on which of the fields have changed, for example if it's a new row they get a phone call with a welcome introduction.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    `OLD_TABLE_NAME` a
WHERE   ROW(a.col1, a.col2, …) NOT IN
    (
    SELECT  *
    FROM    NEW_TABLE_NAME
    )
UNION ALL
SELECT  b.*
FROM    `NEW_TABLE_NAME` b
WHERE   ROW(b.col1, b.col2, …) NOT IN
    (
    SELECT  *
    FROM    OLD_TABLE_NAME
    )
```

Enjoy!

Comment: If I understand your MySQL correctly, this would produce a list of rows that are not found in the new table and also produce a list of rows which have one or more of the fields that are different? What about if a row was deleted from the old table, how would I know it's not a new row in the output?

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a full outer join solution, displaying the "old" values on the left hand side (null in case of addition)  and the new values on the right hand side (null in case of deletion). If both sides are populated it means le line is either unchanged or has the value altered.

```
select key, o.value1, o.value2, m.value1, m.value2
from original o full outer join modifications m using(key)
```

Comment: What about if a row was deleted from the old table, how would I know it's not a new row in the output?